# Mysql datasource connection not getting released on close

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have a mysql datasource configured with 100 connections. It appears that the connections are not getting released to pool even after calling `close()` as below.

```
   public void test() {
       for(1 to 200) {
           try {
               Connection conn1 = datasource.getConnection();
               ResultSet rs = conn1.createStatement().executeQuery(...);
           } finally {
               DBHelper.close(rs);
           }
       }
   }

   //DBHelper.java
   public close(ResultSet rs) {
          Statement stmt = rs.getStatement();
          rs.close();
          Connection conn2 = stmt.getConnection();
          stmt.close();
          conn2.close();
   }
```

After 100, i get an error from `getConnection` API that the pool is empty. If i do `conn1.close()`, it works ok.

```
Failed due to [http-bio-8080-exec-7] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 180 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:180000].
```

I noticed that the type of `conn1` is `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`, while the type of conn2 is `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5`.

The codebase is huge, so would prefer to continue to do this way, as this kind of close seems perfectly ok from API point of view. Is it still possible to close connection using `conn2`?

OS: ubuntu, Tomcat 7.0.52.0. Mysql-Connector-J-20-bin.jar.

Comment: why are yo upassing ResultSet to the method? You can easily pass the connection and use connection.close() method

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, this is an existing codebase and there are quite huge number of such usages.

Comment: what usages? what is the purpose of creating new statement and getting the connection object through that ? i think it is pretty bad design. change the method to accept the connection and just close it there

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, am not creating a new statement. Refer apidoc  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getStatement()

Comment: Yes. but still why you wanna go some crazy way to obtain the connection object, when you directly having and connection reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it like that:

```
   private doClose(ResultSet rs, Connection con) throws Exception {
          if (rs != null) rs.close();

          if (con != null) con.close();
   }
```

That's needs to be the best practice:

```
   public void test() {
       for(1 to 200) {
           Connection conn1 = null;
           ResultSet rs = null;
           try {
               conn1 = datasource.getConnection();
               rs = conn1.createStatement().executeQuery(...);
               .
               .           

           } 
           finally {
                if (conn1 != null) conn1.close();
                if (rs != null) rs.close();        
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that closing with conn1 works. I would prefer to be able to close with conn2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this helps, but Tomcat creates a wrapper around the Connection to pool them:

> Connection pools create wrappers around the actual connection in order to properly pool them. We also create interceptors in these wrappers to be able to perform certain functions. If there is a need to retrieve the actual connection, one can do so using the javax.sql.PooledConnection interface.

You may try this:

```
Connection conn2 = stmt.getConnection();
Connection actual = ((javax.sql.PooledConnection)conn2 ).getConnection();
```

This is stated here (almost at the end of the site): https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

But this would retrieve the real Connection and close it so that you might close a connection from the pool. To hand it back to the pool may try to cast `conn2` to a `PooledConnection` and close that one.